# Write Plugin/addon in android?

Tags: android, plugins, service, aidl

I want to know about how to write a `plugin application` in `android`.

**The requirement is:**

**Plugin Application:** It needs to run in the background like a `background service`.

**Plugin Utilizer application:** It needs to communicate with the `Plugin Application` if needed. As well as send some `data` to `Plugin Application` and receive the `result` based on the sent `data`.

I have googled about the problem, but I am unable get many results.

Though I got one very clear [blog post](http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.in/2010/06/plugins.html) by **Gabor Paller**. Covered details are very clear and informative.

But i wish to know, is this the only way to do this or is there any other way that can be followed ?

Please suggest if you have any alternative way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to enable what you call "Plugin application" in Android.

You can take a look at Roman Nurik's [Muzei](https://github.com/romannurik/muzei) and [Dashclock](https://github.com/romannurik/dashclock) projects, which are great app allowing developer to write their own extensions.